# var value not being recognized outside of each statement

Tags: jquery

When I set the value of var sfp inside the .each statement, the value does not carry to be used outside the .each statement

Here is the piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//using this as testing array
var sspricebreaks = [
"Single Sided Banner",
["0","20","50"],
["3","2","1"]
]

var updateprice = function(){
var h = 24
var w = 48
var q = 5
var tsf = ((h*w)/144)*q;
var sfe = (h*w)/144;
var sfp;

//I am using .reverse because the array is least to greatest but I only need the greatest matched value
$.each(sspricebreaks[1].reverse(), function (index, value) {
    var usevalue;
    if (tsf <= value) {
        var usevalue = ( jQuery.inArray( value, sspricebreaks[1].reverse() ) );

    //this is where I am getting the value for sfp but the value is not updating outside of the .each statement
    var sfp = sspricebreaks[2][usevalue]; 
    return false;
    }
})  

var t = Number.parseFloat(sfe*sfp).toFixed(2);
if (t <= 0) { //Fallback
    t = "0.00";
}
$("#price").text(t);
}

}
```

I need for **var sfp** to be usable in the **var t =** statement at the end of the function but it is only returning "undefined"

Comment: declare **var sfp;** outside the **$.each** loop and continue to use it without re-declaring it into the loop.

Comment: **var sfp** is declared before the **$.each** loop, but I need to redefine the value of it based on results from the array which is why it is in the loop. my problem is that I am having trouble pulling any of the values out of the each loop for use anywhere else. Is there a better way to use the values from the array?

Comment: It's because you've written **var sfp** inside the loop which redefines it as a new variable.
Inside the loop just write **sfp**, not **var sfp**.

Comment: Ah! That fixed it. I feel like this is something I should have know. I apologize for my lack of knowledge there. Thank you gaetanoM and Hq Shiblu.